# TypeError: auto_1.default is not a constructor when unit testing with Jest and Chart.js, Chart constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, chart.js, typeerror

I have a component that imports chart.js/auto and creates a pie chart. The component and file run fine, it's when I run the spec.ts file where I get TypeError: auto_1.default is not a constructor on the new Chart line.

chart.js 3.9.1

jest-canvas-mock 2.4.0

ng-mocks 14.2.3

excerpt from my file (that works):

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
.
.
.
myChart: Chart;
createChart(){
   this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, this.config);
}
```

excerpt from spec.ts file:

```
.
.
.
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

describe('myComponent', () => {
   let component: myComponent;
   let fixture ComponentFixture<myComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [myComponent, MockComponent(otherComponent)],
       imports: [myModules],
       providers: [Utilities, Services]
     }).compileComponents();
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
     component.fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
   }));

   describe('createChart()', () => {
       it('should exist', () => {
          component.createChart();
          expect(component.createChart).toBeCalled();
       }
   })
}
```

```
MyComponent > createChart() > should exist
  TypeError: auto_1.default is not a constructor
     this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, this.config);
                    ^
```

Why would the file work and charts be created and used properly but Jest doesn't see it as a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I solved it by just mocking the import. I'm not interested in testing chart.js, so I don't see any problem with just using a mock object.

I created a mock object in a `chart-stub.ts` file like this:

```
export class Chart {
  public canvas;
  public options;
  public data;
  // this is not a complete mock. You may need to mock other properties as well.


  public constructor(canvas: any, options: any) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.options = options;
    this.data = options.data;
  }
}
```

Then in your jest.config.ts you can swap it like this:

```
{
  displayName: 'YourProject',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    'chart.js/auto$': '<rootDir>/src/app/whatever-location/chart-stub.js'
  }
}
```

And just run it again. Jest will automatically swap any instance for your mock class and will be able to create a new object with it.